# Raspberry Pi Linux kernel module. Realtime for very shord time period

Tags: linux, arm, raspberry-pi, real-time, gpio

I want to connect TCD1304AP CCD array to RPi board. The problem is that when normally clocked (4MHz) TCD1304AP yields ~500 000 samples per second (3648 samples total). So total data reading from CCD array is going to be ~7.3 milliseconds. I want the RPi processor to handle the whole interaction programmatically with GPIO inputs/outputs.

Is it good idea to write a linux kernel module which will disable all interrupts for 7.3 ms and perform all I/O actions according to time diagram and then enable interrupts and return control to OS? What is the common approach to problems like this?

Comment: You could search for GPIO DMA. It can be used for accurate PWM output, at least. I don't know if it can be used for reading, but I'd find it a bit odd if it is for writing only.

Comment: Indeed, [DMA seems feasible](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/10287).

Comment: I managed to interface TCD1304AP with AVR32 UC3A3 66MHz. I ended up using generic clock 2.2MHz (directly divided from CPU CLK PLL) and 550KHz data rate (clock/4) I used internal 8bit ADC of AVR32 you can use any clock source for the main clock you have at disposal and generate the single shift pulse per frame with simple GPIO, then just dummy ADC with DMA or by polling (I use blocking polling loop synchronized by CPU internal clock counter like RDTSC on x86).

Comment: If your GPIO and or ADC is not fast enough you might try electronic shutter however due to bugs in datasheet timings I never managed to get that to work and as I am happy with my current approach (6.7ms per frame) I stopped trying. Also beware the chip is extra sensitive so in order to have valid image data you should cover the chip with thick enough aperture ...